# Why is Jaqen H'ghar captured in the first place with the other two prisoners if he has such skill?

Tags: game-of-thrones, character-motivation

I understand why they were being transported but for someone who is able to change appearance at will and kill anyone with ease I dont get why he didnt just get away at his convenience?

Unless he was planning some sort of hit on someone unknown to us. But things just dont seem to add up.

Did he simply "want" to get captured ? Could he possibly know the tales of events that were to unfold ?

Or is this just how a faceless man "gets around in the world" ?

Whoever caught him must have some skill...

Comment: Just heard an interesting theory, that in fact Jaqen is also Syrio Farell, hired to keep her safe. They are both from Bravos, and you never get true confirmation on Syrio's death. Syrio is hired to keep Arya safe, so it would make sense for his honor bound soul to follow her in some way.

Comment: Syrio was from Braavos. [Jaqen was from Lorath](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jaqen_H%27ghar). Or, at least his persona was. Jaqen himself would surely have *been* on Braavos, since that is where the temple of the many-faced god is, but the logical fallacy is to compare one man's identity with another man's false identity.

Comment: Also, Syrio was hired to be her "dancing master" (i.e. sword fighting teacher), not her bodyguard. He came "highly recommended", Ned said, though, and I've always wondered by whom. Who would Ned Stark trust with his daughters well-being.